# no declaration can be found for element 'neo4j:config'

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, configuration-files

cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 
 'neo4j:config'.

[image]

It is the issue related to the neo4j configuration XML tag "neo4j: config"

Can't resolve the issue by updating the maven. Does anyone face the same issue? Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

check your namespace configuration on top of the configuation file. You might have not added relevant xsd and schema locations.